# Check if my application runs in development/editable mode

Tags: python

My Python application can be install the normal way, or in development/editable mode with `pip`, like this:

```
virtualenv my_app
source my_app/bin/activate
pip install -e my_app
```

How can I make a function to introspect my virtualenv and check if my application runs in development/editable mode?

Is there any "flag" in `sys` module for that?

Motivation: have different configuration in development mode, and in production.

**EDIT:** I compare the *virtualenv* and the *package* directories.

```
import os
import sys

import pkg_resources

main_pkg = 'my_app'
package_dir = pkg_resources.resource_filename(main_pkg, '__init__.py')
virtualenv_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
common_path = os.path.commonprefix([package_dir, virtualenv_dir])
is_dev_mode = not common_path.startswith(virtualenv_dir)
```

I test if the *package_dir* is a subdirectory of the *virtualenv_dir*: if it is not a subdirectory, then I am on development mode.

**EDIT2:**

Is there a more reliable solution?

I want to know if there isn’t a data/a flag in the environment that would clearly indicate to me that my application is running in *development* mode.

What will happen if another dependency is in *development* mode too?

Comment: Note that [Python development mode](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/devmode.html#devmode) is something different than what this question is asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using code from `pip` we can determine this:

```
import pip
import pkg_resources

# I've done `pip install -e .` for a git repo I'm working in inside
# a virtualenv
distributions = {v.key: v for v in pkg_resources.working_set}
# >>> distribution
# pre-commit 0.9.3 (/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit)
distribution = distributions['pre-commit']

# Below is approximately how `pip freeze` works, see the end of
# the answer for a simpler approach, still using pip

# Turn into a pip FrozenRequirement (I'm using pip 9.0.1, it may
# be different for your version)
# I've passed an empty list for the second argument (dependency_links)
# I don't think it's necessary?
frozen_requirement = pip.FrozenRequirement.from_dist(distribution, [])

# Query whether the requirement is installed editably:
print(frozen_requirement.editable)
```

The magic of this comes from a little function inside pip (`pip.utils`):

```
def dist_is_editable(dist):
    """Is distribution an editable install?"""
    for path_item in sys.path:
        egg_link = os.path.join(path_item, dist.project_name + '.egg-link')
        if os.path.isfile(egg_link):
            return True
    return False
```

The `dist` in this is a `pkg_resources` distribution (as we acquired above).  You of course can use the `dist_is_editable` function directly instead of going through `FrozenRequirement`:

```
# With `distribution` as above:
from pip.utils import dist_is_editable
print(dist_is_editable(distribution))  # True in my case ;)
```

Comment: It sounds good ;-) Are the keys of `pkg_resources.working_set` packages names (`import pkg_name`) or library names (like `name="lib_name" in setup.py)?

Comment: The keys will end up being "normalized" package names (so for `yaml` you'll look for `pyyaml`, for `pre_commit` you'll look for `pre-commit`).  The normalization rules follow https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/ (PEP440) (though generally it ends up being `.replace('_', '-').lower()`)

Comment: From pip docs- [_you must not use pip’s internal APIs in this way_](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). And the info is outdated anyway, now whether a distribution is editable or not can be recorded in [`direct_url.json`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/direct-url/) instead of an egg-link.

Comment: @wim well of course this was written in a different time, 5 years ago now :)

Comment: Yeah, although pip didn't really have any public API at that time either (ref: [#4696](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4696)). More to the point, it would be good to update the answer with a way that is currently working/supported.

Comment: that issue is **a year after this post**, the contents of which and the spirit of which still work (the difficult part is locating the egg link / egg info).  the direct_url.json bits came later and are less likely to work unless you can guarantee a pip version

Answer (score 3):

The top solution needs updating for a more recent version of pip, where the FrozenRequirement class is no longer accessible in pip's namespace.

I used this workaround in the relevant lines.

```
from pip._internal.operations.freeze import FrozenRequirement 
frozen_requirement = FrozenRequirement.from_dist(distribution)
```

Comment: even this doesn't work anymore with pip==22.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there's a reliable way to determine this. In fact, I would advise you against testing paths like that because you might run into into different special cases on various operating systems or environments.

There are a few alternatives I recommend instead:

**1)** If this is a command-line utility, I'd recommend to allow loading of a custom configuration file configurable via a command-line flag:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys
import json

parser = ArgumentParser(description='...')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--config', default='config.json')

def main(argv):
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    print('loading config file:', args.config)
    with open(args.config, 'r') as config:
        config = json.loads(config.read())
    print('loaded config', config) 
    # TODO do something with the config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Run with: `python3 test1.py -c config-dev.json`

**2)** If this is not a CLI app, you can achieve a similar thing by using an environment variable:

```
import os
import json

os.environ.get('CONFIG', 'config.json')

def main():
    config_file = os.environ.get('CONFIG', 'config.json')
    print('loading config file:', config_file)
    with open(config_file, 'r') as config:
        config = json.loads(config.read())
    print('loaded config', config) 
    # TODO do something with the config

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Run with: `CONFIG=config-dev.json python3 test2.py`, or:

```
export CONFIG=config-dev.json
python3 test2.py
```

You could also make a shell script to help with set your dev environment, let's call it `customenv`:

```
source env/bin/activate
export CONFIG=config-dev.json
```

And then you could use this file to activate the dev environment:

```
source customenv
```

**3)** If you really wish to have a special case in your code for the development environment, you could specify this via an environment variable too:

```
import os
is_dev_mode = 'MY_APP_DEV' in os.environ and os.environ['MY_APP_DEV'] == '1'
if is_dev_mode:
    print('dev mode!')
```

Run with `MY_APP_DEV=1 python3 test3.py`, or:

```
export MY_APP_DEV=1
python3 -m test3.py
```

**4)** For more customization:

```
import os
app_mode = os.environ.get('MY_APP_MODE', 'prod')
print(app_mode)
```

Comment: I agree with you but this is not what I want. Sorry, but, I really need to check if I am in *development* mode or not.