# How to tell from setup.py if the module is being installed in editable mode

Tags: python, git, setuptools, setup.py

My current setup.py writes the git commit hash in a file which the module can access after it has been installed. However, I would like to disable that when I am developing the module since the setup.py file will not be triggered twice and the hash would be inaccurate. This brings us to the question:

> Is there a way to tell from setup.py whether the module is being installed in editable mode? i.e.,
>
> ```
> pip install -e .
> ```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348746/how-to-detect-if-module-is-installed-in-editable-mode), but even the "hack" will not work in my case since the module will be installed directly with git, and the `.git` directory will exist even for normal installs during installation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just override the correct command. `install` is being run on `pip install .`, `develop` on `pip install --editable .`.

```
# setup.py
from distutils import log
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install as install_orig
from setuptools.command.develop import develop as develop_orig


class develop(develop_orig):

    def run(self):
        self.announce('this code will run on editable install only', level=log.INFO)
        super().run()


class install(install_orig):

    def run(self):
        self.announce('this code will run on normal install only', level=log.INFO)
        super().run()


setup(
    name='spam',
    cmdclass={'install': install, 'develop': develop}
)
```

Test it:

```
$ pip install . -vvv | grep "this code"                                
  this code will run on normal install only
$ pip install -e . -vvv | grep "this code"
  this code will run on editable install only
```

Comment: Could you please update the post to remove the one remaining use of distutils, since it's deprecated?

Comment: And in fact, this also doesn't work. You actually have to override the build_py cmdclass and check the editable_mode attribute as described [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/extension.html#supporting-sdists-and-editable-installs-in-build-sub-commands).