# How can I detect if Python is running in Python Development Mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-development-mode

To turn on [Python Development Mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/devmode.html), you can use this flag:

```
python3 -X dev example.py
```

or use this environment variable:

```
PYTHONDEVMODE=1 python3 example.py
```

How can I write code within `example.py` to detect whether Python is running in Python Development Mode or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if my application runs in development/editable mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530000/check-if-my-application-runs-in-development-editable-mode)

Comment: the doc speak about the variable `__debug__`

Comment: if you use the environment var method you could check `os.environ`

Comment: @SimonHostettler No, that doesn't answer my question, as that question talks about editable mode, not Python Development Mode.

Comment: @rioV8 The variable `__debug__` is True even when Python Development Mode is not on. I just tried it by running `python3` and then running `python3 -X dev`

Comment: It's a bit of a hacky solution, but you should be able to do it by raising one of the exceptions that wouldn't be visible unless you're in development mode, like `DeprecationWarning`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.flags.dev_mode` is True, when running as `python -X dev app.py`